# Change first 2 charecters in cell to integer (with a loop (VBA))

Tags: vba, loops, replace

I was trying to create a script in vba which checks the cell "A1" and replaces the first 2 characters of the string with an integer. Should look something like this:

```
 
 If (Left(A1, 2) = "NI") Then
 newtext = Replace("originaltext", "NI", "801")
 
 ElseIf (Left(A1, 2) = "RE") Then
 newtext = Replace("originaltext", "RE", "821")
 
 ElseIf (Left(A1, 2) = "NV") Then
 newtext = Replace("originaltext", "NV", "571")
 
 ElseIf (Left(A1, 2) = "NF") Then
   newtext = Replace("originaltext", "NF", "831")

end if
  n=n+1
   Loop
```

I want it to go through every cell and do that action starting from a1 lets say all the way down to a2 and a3 and so on.

How do I create the right loop for that?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub flay()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, v As Variant, frst As String
    
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        If Len(v) >= 2 Then
            frst = Left(v, 2)
            If frst = "RE" Then
                Cells(i, "A").Value = Replace(v, "RE", "821")
            ElseIf frst = "NI" Then
                Cells(i, "A").Value = Replace(v, "NI", "801")
            ElseIf frst = "NF" Then
                Cells(i, "A").Value = Replace(v, "NF", "831")
            ElseIf frst = "NV" Then
                Cells(i, "A").Value = Replace(v, "NV", "571")
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testReplaceWithNumber()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  For i = 1 To lastR
    Select Case left(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, 2)
        Case "NI":
            sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "801" & Mid(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, 3)
        Case "RE":
            sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "821" & Mid(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, 3)
        Case "NV":
            sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "571" & Mid(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, 3)
        Case "NF":
            sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "831" & Mid(sh.Range("A" & i).Value, 3)
        End Select
  Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For each cl in 
application.intersect(columns(1),activesheet.usedrange)
      Select case left(cl,2)
         Case "RE"
            Mid(cl,1,2) ="821"
         Case "NI"
           Mid(cl,1,2) ="801"
        ' And so on
      End select
Next
```